# Tkinter Canvas text substitution intermittent

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a method that is called from a button and it allows the user to select a file and pump out an analysis on the other side. There is a canvas outside the class and method that has a text widget that tells the user what is happening, with an original text='Ready'. This is the method that gets it done:

```
def process_solution(self):
    canvas.itemconfig(infobox_text, text='Please Select a File.')
    self.import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()  
    canvas.itemconfig(infobox_text, text='Analysing Solution. Please Wait.')
    if self.import_file_path:
        # UnGzip
        with gzip.open(self.import_file_path, 'rt') as decompressed_buffer:
            decompressed_data = decompressed_buffer.read()
            # Parse to XML
            parsed_data = ElementTree.fromstring(decompressed_data)
            # Now extract metrics
            self.analysis_results = ExtractMetrics.start(parsed_data)
            # Display Parsed Results in Window
            canvas.itemconfig(infobox_text, text=self.analysis_results)

    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(infobox_text, text='Upload Cancelled.')
```

It changes from the original 'Ready' message to 'Please Select a File' with no problem, then it seems to skip 'Analysing Solution. Please Wait.' (even when I put the thread to sleep for a few seconds). And finally it displays self.analysis_results. Even if the file selection is cancelled it displays the right message, but not when a file is selected.

My question is why, if in all cases I'm using *canvas.itemconfig(infobox_text, text=...)* the first, second and fourth changes to the text work, but it skips the third. No errors anywhere either.

Comment: `canvas.itemconfig()`, like all other methods that change widget state, *has no immediate visible effect* - it just marks the widget as having changed state.  The next time the Tkinter mainloop gets a chance to run, all of these changes get made visible.  'Please Select a File' becomes visible only because the file dialog has to run a mainloop of its own, but you're not doing anything like that after the 'Analysing Solution' message.  You can force an update at other times via `canvas.update_idletasks()` (the widget you call it on doesn't matter, the root window would be more typically used).

Comment: If you do some processing that takes too long, the tkinter app's GUI will effectively be "frozen" and no updates to it will be visible until that processing is finished.

Comment: call `canvas.update()` after `canvas.itemconfig`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you all for the explanation. Could one of you guys please put the solution in an answer so I can accept it?